# Alterar tamanho de imagem e box com %, não está funcionando

Tags: html, css, div, height, porcentagem

Tenho um layout, onde tenho uma `div` com uma imagem, e uma `class` com um box por cima dessa imagem, do mesmo tamanho dessa imagem, e aplico um `transition` em cima desse box para revela-lo quando posiciono o mouse por cima dele, e um link nesse box, muito comum em portfólios por exemplo.

Gostaria de usar % no Width e Height, porém não estou conseguindo, se deixo sem o `height`, ou com o `height: auto;`  ele para de funcionar o `transition`.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, desde já agradeço.

Segue o trecho do código html e css:

```css
#proclinica_projetos {
  width: 960px;
  left: 0%;
  top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.box_transicao_proclinica {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 960px;
  height: 960px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para o google chrome*/
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para o firefox*/
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para o opera*/
  transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para IE*/
}
.box_transicao_proclinica:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 960px;
  height: 960px;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para o google chrome*/
  -moz-transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para o firefox*/
  -o-transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para o opera*/
  transition: 0.5s;
  /*propriedade para IE*/
}
```

```html
<div id="proclinica_projetos">
  <img src="imagens/home/proclinica_projetos.png" />
  <div>
    <a href="proclinica.html" class="box_transicao_proclinica"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tentei formatar seu código `html` e `css`, no snippet executável aqui do SO, mas não ficou como você descreveu, acompanhe o mesmo e tente fazer os ajustes, para deixa-lo similar a sua ambiente, para que possamos entender melhor seu problema e possivelmente lhe ajudar. Bem Vindo ao SOpt.

Comment: blza, vou fazer alguns testes e se não conseguir volto com essa alteração.

Answer (score 1):

A princípio você está fazendo uso errado das propriedades de posicionamento, digo isto me baseando no resultado que está buscando.

Se precisa que os elementos internos se ajustem em relação ao *div* pai `proclinica_projetos`, este precisaria ter posição relativa ao invés de absoluta. Nesse caso, sendo relativa, utilizar `width:100%` e `height:100%` teria o resultado esperado (desde que o elemento pai tenha a largura e altura definidas).

---

Uma forma, talvez um pouco melhor seja posicionar de forma absoluta os elementos filhos.

```
.filho {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0; /* "100%" de largura */
    bottom: 0; top: 0  /* "100%" de altura  */
}
```

Eis um exemplo:

```css
.pai {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px
}

/**
  Ocupando toda a área do div pai */
.filho {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; top: 0
}

.atras {
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmqkH.jpg);
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover
}

.frente {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
            transition: all 400ms ease-in;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff
}

.frente:hover {
    background: transparent
}
```

```html
<div class='pai'>
    <div class='filho atras'></div>
    <div class='filho frente'>HOVER ME</div>
</div>
```

---

#### Adaptando para o seu caso...

Como precisa que esse conteúdo seja "clicável", utilizando a técnica anterior basta tornar o `a` um elemento de bloco:

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px
}

.box a, .box img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; top: 0
}

.box img {
    height: 100%
}

.box a {
    -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease-in;
            transition: all 400ms ease-in;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff
}

.box a:hover {
    background: transparent
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
    <img alt='' src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmqkH.jpg'/>
    <a href='http://pt.stackoverflow.com'>Hover/Click me</a>
</div>
```

#### Bônus:

Sempre utilize `box-sizing:border-box` em seu CSS para evitar surpresas com relação ao tamanho dos elementos, [este artigo explica melhor o porque com alguns exemplos](http://sergiolopes.org/css-box-sizing-border-box/).

---

<sup>**OBS:** Em ambos os exemplos utilizei a propriedade `transition` com suporte somente a navegadores *webkit* e o *Firefox* para não tornar o código extenso. No entanto, na hora de colocar no seu site, não esqueça de dar suporte ao Internet Explorer e Opera.</sup>

Comment: valeu, muito obrigado, vou fazer os testes aqui e volto pra dar retorno.

Comment: @Juliocesar deu certo?

Comment: Olá @Renan, desculpa a demora em responder. Então deu mais ou menos certo. Consegui aplicar seu exemplo no elemento que fica à direta da página, esse que mostrei, mas em outros que ficam à esquerda e abaixo, não consegui mesmo. Tentei alterar os left, right, top e bottom e nada.

Answer (score 0):

eu entendi o que você estava tentando fazer, apesar da pergunta ter ficado confusa, poderia ter dito apenas que precisava colocar um efeito ao passar o mouse.

de toda forma, não precisava fazer assim, você não colocou nada dentro desse "box", só serviu para ocupar espaço, faça desta forma que dará certo:

```
.image{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(100%);
}
.image:hover{
    -webkit-filter:grayscale(0%);
    transition: 1s;
}


<div id="proclinica_projetos">
    <a href="proclinica.html" class="box_transicao_proclinica"> 
      <img src="imagens/home/proclinica_projetos.png" class="image">
    </a>
</div>
```

se você busca algo mais sofisticado, como mostrar um texto ao passar o mouse na imagem, faça assim:

```
<style>
    .imagem {
      position: relative;
    }
    .capa {
      display: none;
    }

    .imagem:hover .capa {
      display: block;
    }

    .capa {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
</style>

    <div class="imagem">
     <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" >
     <div class="capa">
       <h1>Título</h1>
       <p>Aqui vem o texto</p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui tem um exemplo para wordpress: https://www.anicasagrande.com.br/detalhes-que-aparecem-quando-passa-o-mouse-sobre-imagem/